# CSV import in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, csv, yii2

### What i did?

I have trying to upload csv file in my project module.The csv format is given below.At the time of upload getting  Error message "1 Row has Validation Error".
The values are not inserted in db.

### What i want?

I want to upload my csv file data in my mysql db.

```
      **My CSV Format**
==============================================================================
model_name|imei_no|promoter_vendor_id|device_report_id|allocation_date
==============================================================================
sam       | 2342  |     7            |   3             |2015
==============================================================================
```

### **Insert Query  Mysql**

```
INSERT INTO `dbname`.`tbl_device`
(`device_id`,`model_name`,`imei_no`,`promoter_vendor_id`,`device_report_id`,
`allocation_date`,`inserted_date`,`inserted_ip`,`inserted_by`,`updated_date`,
`updated_ip`,`updated_by`,`status_in`,`record_status`)VALUES
(Auto_inc,sam,34234,7,3,2015,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

### **Model Import function**

```
In model i am trying to create insert query in yii model.

function device_insert_by_csvfile()
{
/* Table name*/
    $table='tbl_device'; 
    $row = 1;
    $field='';
    $value='';
    $success=0;
    $error=0;
    //Check the file available or not

    if(file_exists('device_csv.csv')){
    $handle = fopen('device_csv.csv', "r");
        $valueComa='';
    $model_name=$imei_no=$promoter_vendor_id=$device_report_id=$allocation_date=-1;

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
     {
    $num = count($data);echo "<script>alert(".$num.");</script>";
        // Skip Validate Error Row
        if( $row !=1 && (trim($data[$model_name])=='' ||      trim($data[$imei_no])=='' || trim($data[$promoter_vendor_id])=='' || trim($data[$device_report_id]) || trim($data[$allocation_date]) =='')){
                  $error++;
                    continue;
          }

          // Table Fields Binding
            if($row ==1){ 
                $coma='';
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    if(trim($data[$c])=='model_name'){
                        $model_name=$c;
                    }
                    if(trim($data[$c])=='imei_no'){
                        $imei_no=$c;
                    }
                    if(trim($data[$c])=='promoter_vendor_id'){
                        $promoter_vendor_id=$c;
                    }
                    if(trim($data[$c])=='device_report_id'){
                        $device_report_id=$c;
                    }
                    if(trim($data[$c])=='allocation_date'){
                        $allocation_date=$c;
                    }
                    $field.= $coma.trim($data[$c]);
                    $coma=',';
                }
            }
            //Values Binding
            else{
                // Successfully Inserted Row Count
                $success++;
                $totId++;
                // Insert record value Binding
                $value.=$valueComa."(";
                $vcoma='';
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    if($promoter_vendor_id ==$c &&  trim($data[$c]) !=''){

                        $ftype=UserType::find()->where("id='$data[$c]' OR type               like'%$data[$c]%'")->asArray()->one(); 
                        if(count($ftype) >0){
                            $value.=$vcoma."'".$ftype['id']."'" ;
                            $vcoma=',';
                        }else{
                            $value.=$vcoma."'0'" ;
                            $vcoma=',';
                        }                   
                    }else{
                        $value.=$vcoma."'".addslashes(trim($data[$c]))."'" ;
                        $vcoma=',';
                    }

                }
               $value.=")";
               $valueComa=',';
            }
              $row++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
        unlink('device_csv.csv');
    if($value !=''){    
            $sql ="insert into $table ($field) values $value";
            $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
            $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
            $dataReader=$command->execute();
        }
    }
    return array($success,$error);
    }
```

### **My View page**

```
<!-- Device import and export -->


<div class="tab-pane" id="device"> 
                            <br/>
                            <?php if(!empty($deverror)){?>

                                <div class="alert alert-danger"><?=$deverror?> <?=Yii::t('app', $deverror=='1'?'Row has':'Rows have')?>  <?=Yii::t('app', 'Validation Error')?></div>

                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if(!empty($devmsg)){?>

                                <div class="alert alert-success"><?=$devmsg?>  <?=Yii::t('app', $devmsg=='1'?'Row has':'Rows have')?> <?=Yii::t('app', 'been Successfully Inserted')?></div>

                            <?php } ?>
                            <form  action="" id="device_frm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:inline">

                              <?php Yii::$app->request->enableCsrfValidation = true; ?>

                                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?php echo $this->renderDynamic('return Yii::$app->request->csrfToken;'); ?>">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <i><?=Yii::t('app', 'Note: File Type should be "csv"')?></i>
                                    (
                                    <i style="color:#F00; font-size:12px"><?=Yii::t('app', 'Required Fields*: model_name,imei_no,promoter_id,device_report(mins)')?></i>
                                    )
                                    <br><br>
                                    <label><?=Yii::t('app', 'CSV File')?></label>

                                    <input type="file" name="device_csv_file" class="form-control" id="device_csv_file" data-validation="required">

                                </div>

                                <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Device CSV'), ['class' => 'btn btn-sm  btn-primary device_submit']) ?>

                            </form>
                            <?php if(isset($_FILES['device_csv_file'])){?>
                            <form  action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:inline">
                              <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?php echo $this->renderDynamic('return Yii::$app->request->csrfToken;'); ?>">
                              <input type="hidden" name="device_csv_upload" value="true">   
                               <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Import File'), ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary customer_csv_upload']) ?>
                            </form>

                            <?php } ?>
                            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" target="_blank" href="../../livefactory/csv_files/device_template.csv" data-original-title="" title="">
                                <span class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></span>
                                 <?=Yii::t('app', 'Download Device CSV Import Template')?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use vendor's library. For example: https://github.com/ruskid/yii2-csv-importer

Answer (score 0):

According to the MySQL query you post, there are missing quotes around `sam`

```
INSERT INTO `dbname`.`tbl_device` 
(`device_id`, `model_name`, `imei_no`, `promoter_vendor_id`,
`device_report_id`, `allocation_date`, `inserted_date`,
`inserted_ip`, `inserted_by`, `updated_date`, `updated_ip`,
`updated_by`, `status_in`,`record_status`)
VALUES (Auto_inc, 'sam', 34234, 7,3,2015,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

During the parsing of the csv line, you should create a array $string to mark `$string[0]=true;` (0 is the index of the model_name column) then add quotes in the second loop if `$string[$c] === true`. I don't copy / paste the solution are there is a lot of code here to just change 2 ou 3 lines.

Hope it helps.